# How to load a datasource with multiple objects at a time in WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework, datagrid, lambda

I have two objects with same properties obj1 and Obj2 . but the values in these objects are different.  I  want to combine these object and the result I want to bind to the Itemsource of the datagrid.Is that possible using lambda expession/Linq ?

Comment: show us some example data pls.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `Properties` are limited then I have a simple solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
     List<Data1> _data1= new List<Data1>{new Data1{Name="Test11"},new Data1{Name="Test12"}};

     List<Data2> _data2=new List<Data2>{new Data2{Name="Test21"},new Data2{Name="Test22"}};

     List<Common> _common = new List<Common>();

     _common.AddRange(_data1.ConvertToCommon());
     _common.AddRange(_data2.ConvertToCommon());

     foreach(var item in _common)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
       }

    }
}

class Data1
{
  public string Name{get;set;}    

}

class Data2
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
}


class Common
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
}


static class Extension
{
  public static IEnumerable<Common> ConvertToCommon(this IEnumerable<Data1> data)
  {
    foreach(var item in data)
      yield return new Common{Name=item.Name};
  }

  public static IEnumerable<Common> ConvertToCommon(this IEnumerable<Data2> data)
  {
    foreach(var item in data)
      yield return new Common{Name=item.Name};
  }
}
```

Then you can use the `Common` class to Bind to UI. The other option is to use `MultiBinding` and then a `IMultiValueConverter`. Again you need to Cast to a data type.